# How to delete one image from a set of images by image id PHP

Tags: php, mysql, image

I have a system where a user can view all the images they've uploaded to a blog post they created (this is a non-wordpress site). From there, I want them to be able to delete any images they want. I have everything setup and working, except for the actual delete function. I'm displaying this images by using a loop.

I know I need to delete the images by their unique `img_id`s they're assigned, but I am stuck on how to do that. I've tried several different things, which have all resulted in errors. With what I have below, I am not getting any errors, the function is just not working how I would like.

I'm still in the process of getting my feet wet when it comes to PHP and would appreciate it if someone could give me an idea of how to proceed. Thanks in advance.

Here is the code for the delete function I have at the top of the page:

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
       $img_id = $_POST['delete_rec_id'];  
       $deletequery = "DELETE FROM images WHERE img_id=$img_id"; 
       $deleteresult = mysqli_query($db,$deletequery);
   }
?>
```

Here is the code for where the images are being displayed in the html body:

```
<?php 
  $imsql = "SELECT img_name, img_path, img_id 
            FROM images 
            WHERE post_id = '$id'";
  $q2 = $db->query($imsql);
     if($q2->num_rows>0){
       while ($imrow = $q2->fetch_object()){  
           echo '<img src="images/' . $imrow->img_name . '" width="100%" height="auto"/>';
           echo '<br><br>';
           echo '<form id="delete" method="post" action="">';
             echo '<input type="hidden" name="delete_rec_id" value="<?php print $img_id; ?>" /> ';
             echo '<input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete Image" class="btn btn-default"/>  ';
           echo '</form>';
           echo '<br><br><br><br>';
       }
     }
  ?>
```

Here is the entire batch of code at the top of my page in case anything else is needed:

```
<?php
session_start();
$msg = "";

if(!isset($_GET['id'])){
  header('Location: modify.php');
  exit();
}else{
  $id = $_GET['id'];
}

include('../includes/db_connect.php');

if(!is_numeric($id)){
  header('Location: modify.php');
}

if(isset($_POST['delete'])){
       $img_id = $_POST['delete_rec_id'];  
       $deletequery = "DELETE FROM images WHERE img_id=$img_id"; 
       $deleteresult = mysqli_query($db,$deletequery);
    }

$sql = "SELECT * FROM post WHERE post_id='$id'";
$query = $db->query($sql);
if($query->num_rows !=1){
  header('Location: modify.php');
  exit();
}

?>
```

**Edit:** I realized I am trying to run a `<?php print ?>` in the following echo statement:  `echo '<input type="hidden" name="delete_rec_id" value="<?php print $img_id; ?>" /> ';`

I'm thinking this is what the issue is. How would I go about writing a print statement within an echo statement?

***ANSWER FOR FUTURE REFERENCE:***

```
<?php 
        $imsql = "SELECT img_name, img_path, img_id FROM images WHERE post_id = '$id'";
        $q2 = $db->query($imsql);
        if($q2->num_rows>0){
          while ($imrow = $q2->fetch_object()){  
            echo '<img src="images/' . $imrow->img_name . '" width="100%" height="auto"/>';
            echo '<br><br>';
            echo '<form id="delete" method="post" action="">';
              echo '<input type="hidden" name="delete_rec_id" value="' . $imrow->img_id . '" /> ';
              echo '<input type="submit" name="delete" value="Delete Image" class="btn btn-default"/>  ';
            echo '</form>';
            echo '<br><br><br><br>';
        }
      }
        ?>
```

Comment: Your code is dangerous due to SQL-injection, use prepared statements: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI I don't like how you did this code, but that's my personal preference.

But your fix is fairly easy (You just didn't address the array)
Change

```
 echo '<input type="hidden" name="delete_rec_id" value="<?php print $img_id; ?>" /> ';
```

to

```
 echo '<input type="hidden" name="delete_rec_id" value="<?php print $imrow->img_id; ?>" /> ';
```

Comment: Oh thank you for pointing that out! I completely overlooked it. I went ahead and changed it, and I still cannot get it to work. However, I think that's because I realized I'm trying to run a `<?php print ?>` in that echo statement. I'm thinking this is what the issue is (aside from me not addressing the array as you pointed out). Do you have any suggestions on how to go about using a print statement within an echo statement? If that's even possible at all.

Comment: if you can't echo in an echo, then use printf